# why this code does not working in python with sqlizer module?

Tags: python, sql

I have a table containing a list of tables to convert with sqlizer, this is the code, but it doesn't work, can someone help me?
Thanks

```
import os
import sqlizer
sqlizer.config.API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
os.chdir('C:/metadati/asim/asim_metadati/')
print("Current working directory: {0}".format(os.getcwd()))
Current working directory: C:\metadati\asim\asim_metadati
with open(r'c:/metadati/asim/asim_metadati/filelist.txt', 'r') as fn:
        for line in fn:
            with open(line.rstrip(), mode='r') as file_content:
                
                converter = sqlizer.File(file_content, sqlizer.DatabaseType.SQLServer, sqlizer.FileType.XML, file_content, 'my_table')          

converter.convert(wait=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    converter.convert(wait=True)
  File "C:\Users\egiag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlizer\file.py", line 182, in convert
    self._upload_data()
  File "C:\Users\egiag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlizer\file.py", line 129, in _upload_data
    buffer = self._file.read(self.SQLIZER_MULTIPART_UPLOAD_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
f=(converter.download_result_file().text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    f=(converter.download_result_file().text)
  File "C:\Users\egiag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlizer\file.py", line 188, in download_result_file
    req = requests.get(self.result_url)
  File "C:\Users\egiag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\egiag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\egiag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\egiag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\egiag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 316, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\egiag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 390, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?
```

**this code does not work**

Here below the table tha i read.

`filelist.txt`

```
ASCII-protocol-270.xml
ASCII-protocol-271.xml
ASCII-protocol-272.xml
ASCII-protocol-273.xml
ASCII-protocol-274.xml
ASCII-protocol-275.xml
```

Comment: Edit your code so that the input data is a list of lines in the code.  Anyone else can then run is.  And read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.